# Customize NavigationDrawer to have diagonal side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to customise the NavDrawer in the following fashion.
 [image: Customised NavDrawer]

I couldn't find relevent pointers from google..let me know if this could be done by customising the view and how?

Answer (score 0):

Since the nav drawer is always the same width, the way I would do this is just create a background image with the background color, and an invisible slice on the bottom corner:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
| This section is                   |
| background color                  |
| e.g. 0xFF000000                  /|
| (full black,                    / |
|  alpha == 1.0)                 /  |
|                               /   |
|                              /    |
|                             /     |
|                            /      |
|                           /       |
|                          /        |
|                         /         |
|                        /          |
|                       /           |
|                      /            |
|                     /             |
|                    /              |
|                   / This section  |
|                  / invisible e.g. |
|                 /  0x00000000     |
|                /   (alpha == 0.0) |
+-----------------------------------+
```

This would be very easy to with PhotoShop, for example.

If you want the nav drawer to close when touched in that invisible area, I would overlay the entire menu with a view having an `onTouchEventListener()` that would hit test for the `TouchEvent` `ACTION_UP` in that invisible area, closing the drawer if inside the area and returning `false` (event not handled) if outside the area.

Comment: ok, viable. But I want the drawer to closed if clicked in the invisible region. 
That will not happen unless its a different screen down there?